# Not printing after if statment

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax

So I have just started learning to use Python, and I am getting a syntax error.

Following the book I am using , here is a simple if statement, followed by a print statement that happens regardless of the if statement.

```
name = "Doug"
if name == 'Doug' :
    print "Hello, Doug!"
print "How are you today?"
```

The expected output is:

```
Hello Doug!
How are you today?
```

if `name != Doug`, then the output should be

```
How are you today?
```

I've done simple ifs a thousand times in C++ and Java, but with brackets. For some reason, the final print comes back with a syntax error.

I am using Python 2.7.8, not Python 3, and using `print` or `print()` gives me the same result.

EDIT:
 No amount of Newlines in the interpreter version worked, however running the script in a .py file worked flawlessly. For some reason , my book failed to mention this.

Comment: Please show us the full traceback of the error; the code, as posted, works.

Comment: Check your indentation. Tabs vs. spaces is a typical source of confusion.

Comment: Also, if you copied the code from a web page, we weary of non-breaking spaces or zero-width joiners.

Comment: Last but not least, if you paste the code straight into a Python session, then you need a *newline* between the two `print` statements as otherwise the interpreter won't see it as a separate block.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me if I put it in a .py file and run the file through the interpreter.  E.g. `python hello.py`.  If I run the python interpreter interactively, however, then I can reproduce a syntax error at the second print statement.

I think this is just a quirk of interactive mode.  I can make it work in interactive mode, too, by putting an extra newline between the two `print` statements.  For what it's worth, the interactive-mode prompting makes me think that it doesn't recognize the end of the `if` statement until I type that extra newline after it (otherwise, another statement in the `if` block might follow).

Comment: The interactive interpreter cannot just guess as to when a compound  construct is entered, so it uses empty lines instead.

Comment: See the [interactive input grammar](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/toplevel_components.html#interactive-input); *Note that a (top-level) compound statement must be followed by a blank line in interactive mode; this is needed to help the parser detect the end of the input.*